# Creating a list from a number, then creating sheets from the list

Tags: vba, excel

Could someone please help me with the following: If the user puts "10" in B6 on a sheet called "Data", then B7 downwards will count up to the number e.g. B7 will be "1", B8 will be "2", B9 will be "3", and so on.
The user then puts a value to the right of those numbers and clicks a on screen button the following new sheets are created from a template sheet called "ML".
e.g. B6 is "1" and C6 is "3" then 4 sheets are created (a copy of "ML") called "1.1", "1.2", and "1.3"
B7 is "2" and C7 is "5" then 5 sheets are created (a copy of "ML") called "2.1", "2.2", "2.3", "2.4", and "2.5"

**Image Illustrating problem**

[image]

Comment: Please, give it your best shot and ask for help when you encounter problems you cannot resolve (after doing your research).

Comment: [Image of issue](http://imgur.com/MeIp3KD)

Comment: Your image does not match your description. Is the user intended to type a number into B6 or A6? Are the initial series of numbers to be generating starting B7 or B6?

Answer (score 0):

I worked all of the code into a single `Worksheet_Change` event macro. This may be more automatic than you intended. Error control to avoid attempting to create a worksheet with a duplicate name should be added.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Address = "$B$6" Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        With Target.Offset(1, 0)
            Range(.Cells(1), .Cells(1).End(xlDown)).ClearContents
            .Value = 1
            .Resize(Target.Value, 1).DataSeries _
              Rowcol:=xlColumns, Type:=xlLinear, Step:=1
        End With
        Target.Offset(0, 1).Activate
    ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Columns("C")) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Row > 6 And Application.Count(Target.Offset(0, -1).Resize(1, 2)) = 2 Then
            On Error GoTo Fìn
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Dim w As Long
            For w = 1 To Target.Value
                Sheets.Add(after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = _
                  Target.Offset(0, -1) & Chr(46) & w
            Next w
            Me.Activate
        End If
    End If
Fìn:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

If you prefer a button to create the additional worksheets and are having trouble peeling out the relevant section of code, post back showing your own effort (noting any line that generates a error). As noted above, error control for duplicate worksheet names should definitely be addressed.

Comment: Thanks @Jeeped, but I'm still having trouble getting the it to copy a sheet (to use as a template) and then giving it a the name "Unit 1.1". `Sheets("Unit").Copy(after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))..Name = _
                  Target.Offset(0, -1) & Chr(46) & w `